# C#でバイト配列からstringを得るには？

Tags: c#

UTF8であることがわかっているバイト配列(`byte[]`)から`string`を得るにはどうしたら良いですか？Javaでいう`new String(data)`みたいな方法が知りたいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Encodingクラス](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx)の[UTF8プロパティ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.text.encoding.utf8(v=vs.110).aspx)、[GetStringメソッド](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/744y86tc(v=vs.110).aspx)を使います。

```
var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```